# junit custom ParameterSupplier

Tags: junit

all of the samples i've seen online with regard to custom parametersuppliers have something like:

```
List<PotentialAssignment> list = new ArrayList<PotentialAssignment>();
list.add(PotentialAssignment.forValue("teams", "giants"));
list.add(PotentialAssignment.forValue("teams", "jets"));
list.add(PotentialAssignment.forValue("teams", "niners"));
return list;
```

now, the question i have is: what does the first argument to PotentialAssignment.forValue(arg1, arg2) do?  Nothing i've seen online has explained the significance of it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `PotentialAssignment.forValue` is the "name" of the value. It is **not** used, if your `@Theory` method passes, but if it fails, it is used to assemble the error message. Here is an example:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class CustomParameterSupplierTest {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
    @ParametersSuppliedBy(FooSupplier.class)
    public @interface Foo {}

    public static class FooSupplier extends ParameterSupplier {
        @Override
        public List<PotentialAssignment> getValueSources(ParameterSignature sig) {
            return Arrays.asList(
                PotentialAssignment.forValue("one", 1),
                PotentialAssignment.forValue("two", 2)
            );
        }
    }

    @Theory
    public void test(@Foo int foo) {
        assertThat(foo, is(1));
    }
}
```

If this test is executed with Junit 4.11 you will get the following error:

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: test(two)
```

By the way, in the upcoming release JUnit 4.12 the error reporting is further improved and you will get the following error:

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: test("2" <from two>)
```